# Why would INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS ever return a value less than 64?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to figure out what values I can expect for the Windows macro `_INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS`.
MSDN's [__int64 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261215%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) says that this code should be used whenever using `__int64`

```
#if defined (_INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS) && \
      _INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS >= 64
    typedef signed __int64 int64;
    typedef unsigned __int64 uint64;
#else
    #error __int64 type not supported
#endif
```

Why would I ever see a value below 32 for `INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS`? The answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be)  show that on 32 bit Windows, a `long long` is 64 bits.  [VS2013 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) states that

> _INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS - Reports the maximum size (in bits) for an integral type as an integer literal.

Since `long long` is an integral type, the lowest value that should be returned, even on 32 bit Windows, is 64 bits, right?
Why is the `_INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS >= 64` portion of the `#if` necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That documentation is for Visual Studio 6.0. Visual Studio 6.0 was released in 1998, which was before any `long long` was standardised, and did not support it. It did support the `__int64` you see in the documentation, so that *could* be unconditionally used, but presumably the check on `_INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS` is to get a better error message for even older versions of Visual Studio. "__int64 type not supported" is a useful error message. Something like "syntax error before unexpected token 'int64'" is not a useful error message.