# A LONGLONG data type in windows api

Tags: winapi

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) MSDN page, a data type LONGLONG is defined as below.

```
#if !defined(_M_IX86)
 typedef __int64 LONGLONG; 
#else
 typedef double LONGLONG;
#endif
```

And it says LONGLONG is a 64-bit signed integer. But `double` is a floating-point type, not an integer type. So, do I find a typo? Or am I missing a point?

Comment: No it's not but it's a bit more complicated. Here's an extract from winnt.h https://pastebin.com/raw/Zz8Qbrb9 it's really for architectures/compiler that would know about double (which is ancient, 40 years old) but don't know about 64-bit sized integer, a best (blittable, binary compatible) effort. For example, I think VBA 32-bit doesn't have any int64 integer (LongLong) so developers use double for passing an int64 through apis. It's a similar scenario.

Comment: @SimonMourier That's good to remind that eventually a compiler decides how to read double. But two things confuse me. 1. Why did Microsoft choose a double which is already used against human convention or standards? 2. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019) page says double is 64bit floating point type in microsoft c++ 32bit and 64bit compilers. In my understanding winapi c++ code is also compiled in Visual Studio IDE. But why is double specially interpreted in that context?

Comment: Humans are really out of the loop here. As for standards and conventions, I told you, double is the only ancient well-known/standardized type that is 64-bit. But fear nothing, no recent (recent like 20 years) Microsoft Compiler will end up compiling LONGLONG as a double, even if you compile as x86. This is really an edge case today, but try to think yourself 25 years ago.

Comment: @SimonMourier Oh, I'm sorry I misunderstood. I thought you said like 'double is the same as 64bit integer type'. Now I get the point. I should rather learn English more.. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a documentation bug. It looks to be a lossy conversion from source to documentation<sup>1</sup>. The actual definition in *winnt.h* is a fair bit more complex:

```cpp
//
// __int64 is only supported by 2.0 and later midl.
// __midl is set by the 2.0 midl and not by 1.0 midl.
//

#define _ULONGLONG_
#if (!defined (_MAC) && (!defined(MIDL_PASS) || defined(__midl)) && (!defined(_M_IX86) || (defined(_INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS) && _INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS >= 64)))
typedef __int64 LONGLONG;
typedef unsigned __int64 ULONGLONG;

#define MAXLONGLONG                         (0x7fffffffffffffff)


#else

#if defined(_MAC) && defined(_MAC_INT_64)
typedef __int64 LONGLONG;
typedef unsigned __int64 ULONGLONG;

#define MAXLONGLONG                      (0x7fffffffffffffff)


#else
typedef double LONGLONG;
typedef double ULONGLONG;
#endif //_MAC and int64

#endif
```

To understand what's going on, let's strip this down by removing everything not immediately relevant.

- Assume that `defined(_MAC)` evaluates to 0.
- Assume that `defined(_INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS) && _INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS >= 64` evaluates to 1. That [appears to be true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27005075/1889329) even going back as far as Visual C++ 6.0.
- Strip symbols not relevant here (`_ULONGLONG_`, `ULONGLONG`, `MAXLONGLONG`).
- Apply indentation without changing any other semantics.

The definition is now a lot easier to parse:

```cpp
//
// __int64 is only supported by 2.0 and later midl.
// __midl is set by the 2.0 midl and not by 1.0 midl.
//

#if !defined(MIDL_PASS) || defined(__midl)
    typedef __int64 LONGLONG;
#else
    typedef double LONGLONG;
#endif
```

With that it should be clear that the conditional is a guarding the MIDL compiler (not the C++ compiler). The comment above has rationale, too: Version 1 of the MIDL compiler<sup>2</sup> didn't support `__int64` as a keyword, but version 2 (and later) do.

Translated into English: If this code isn't parsed by the MIDL compiler, or the MIDL compiler's version is 2 or above, alias `LONGLONG` with `__int64`. Otherwise (that is, using the MIDL compiler version 1), pick a `double` as a best effort.

This is of little practical use today. You can assume that `LONGLONG` is an alias for `__int64`, regardless of whether the definition is pulled in by the MIDL or C++ compiler. I wasn't able to find a version history for MIDL.exe, but I assume that version 1 is "ancient".

---

<sup>1</sup> *I'm reluctant to accept that having .NET developers write the tooling to generate C documentation from source was a Good Idea™.*
<sup>2</sup> *This refers to the compiler version, not the MIDL language version.*

Answer (score 2):

With your code snippet, I think it is approach to guarantee that **LONGLONG** is 64bit under your environment Because **double** is the only 64bit type which is supported by *_M_IX86* in the standard, maybe POSIX. The standard has no **__int64** type.